# How can I change OWA's error page?

Tags: exchange-2010

We are running Exchange 2010 and using webmail via Exchange OWA. When you go to a path that does not exist it seems like owa shows its own detailed error message outside of IIS Detailed Errors cause those are turned off. When I go to a URL where a ASPX page doesn't exist it displays a 404 error, but also displays the Exception information or detailed error message. I can't figure out how to turn off OWA detailed error messages.

We I've looked in several places now and Exchange OWA is still showing detailed errors.

In example:

> Request Url: https://webmail.bicsi.org:443/owa/auth/copy login.aspx
>
> OWA version: 14.2.390.1
>
> Exception
>
> Exception type: System.Web.HttpException
>
> Exception message: The file '/owa/auth/copy login.aspx' does not exist.

How do I turn these off?

Comment: This question shows a lack of [basic research](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask), please re-read [how to ask a good question](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello,

We are running Exchange 2010 and using webmail via Exchange OWA. When you go to a path that does not exist it seems like owa shows its own detailed error message outside of IIS Detailed Errors cause those are turned off. 

When I go to a URL where a ASPX page doesn't exist it of course displays a 404 error, but also displays the Exception information or detailed error message information. 

I can't figure out how to turn of OWA detailed error messages. The IIS messages are off and not displaying. I don't want to show these messages.

Comment: Have you tried googling this question?

Comment: Yes and I can't seem to find anything on it except for doing within IIS which I've already done.